# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' while running server in virtual environment

Tags: python, django

i am new in python learning.after learning python basics i have moved to learn python web framework Django. for this

---

i followed these steps for installing django on my windows after installing python 3.7

1. first i opens cmd command prompt (C:\users\mypcname)
2. then i  created virtual environment wrapper with command **pip install virtualenvironmentwrapper-win**
3. then i created virtual environment with command **mkvirtualenv test**
4. then i entered command **workon test** to enable virtual environment
5. then tried to install django with command **pip install django** and its successfully installed
6. then i created projects directory with command **mkdir djangoprojects**
7. then i created app directory in djangoprojects(which i created in last step) with **command django-admin startproject firstproject**
8. then i moved to firstproject with command cd..
9. there i tried to run server with **command python manage.py runserver** and got error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   main
>       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in
>   
>       main()   File "manage.py", line 12, in main
>       raise ImportError( ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment
>   variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

---

can anyone guide me what i have done here wrong  ? why its showing error

Comment: check if you installed django in the environment. To do that activate the environment and call pip freeze.

Comment: @t.stv i tried to check by going to environment workon test then i typed django-admin --version its showing django version 3.0.5 means its installed in environment (but when i check its version outside the environment its showing version there too means its installed there too). what is freez ?

Comment: @t.stv    (test) C:\Users\dewams-junaidpc>pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==3.2.7
distlib==0.3.0
Django==3.0.5
filelock==3.0.12
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.18
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.6

Comment: looks ok, check your pythonpath in evironment variables

Comment: there is only 1 env variable test which i am using

Comment: you need to have pythonpath variable there it should point to the python interpreter

Comment: @t.stv how to find correct path of python interpreter

Comment: well enter the folder where you installed it

Comment: ok i will try new method, still problem not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution by myself. actually i had downloaded python twice with different versions also i had downloaded python   with anaconda package. i uninstalled all python versions and anaconda from my computer then i reinstalled python from his official website. then i tried above method which works fine.thanks to myself