# Python/Docker ImportError: Couldn't import Django but it's installed

Tags: python, django, docker, virtualenv

I am trying to run a microservices program through my manager.py file that uses docker, but when I run the program using `docker-compose up` I get an ImportError that tells me that Django is not installed even though it is. I have tried to use the `venv` library to create and install Django using my virtual environment `vegatestnet`, have also tried to change my Windows path variable to point to the project, and finally, I have tried to even use `import sys print(sys.path)` to find where my `PYTHON_PATH` is but no dice.
I have also tried to use these links to help me: [ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830454/importerror-couldnt-import-django-are-you-sure-its-installed-and-available-o), [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' while running server in virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286746/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-while-running-server-in-virtual-en), and [Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? --> WSGI.PY file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479892/couldnt-import-django-are-you-sure-its-installed-and-available-on-your-python) and I have tried their solutions but I still get this error.
Here is the directory structure that I am working with:

```
-veganettest
 ...
 -posts (folder)
 -profiles (folder)
  ...
  producer.py (my producer file)
 -static_cdn (folder)
 -static_project (folder)
 ...
 -veganettest (folder)
 -vegatestnet (virtual envoirment folder)
 admin (my admin file)
 consumer.py (my consumer file)
 db.sqlite3 (database file)
 docker-compose.yml (docker compose file)
 Dockerfile (just the dockerfile)
 manage.py (manager file - file where I am getting the error)
 requirements.txt (import file)
```

Here is the error that I am getting when I run the program:

```
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 | ['C:\\app', 'C:\\Python\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Python\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\Python', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |   File "C:\app\manage.py", line 11, in main
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |   File "C:\app\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |     main()
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |   File "C:\app\manage.py", line 13, in main
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 |     raise ImportError(
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
veganettest_queue_1 exited with code 1
7e1fb27ba719_veganettest_backend_1 exited with code 1
```

And here are my manage.py, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and requirements.txt files respectively:

manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

print(sys.path)
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'veganettest.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line #line where I am receiving the error
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/trevo/OneDrive/Desktop/veganet/veganettest:c:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  queue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python -u consumer.py'
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: vegatest
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==4.0.2
djangorestframework==3.12.2
mysqlclient==2.0.1
django-mysql==3.9
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
pika==1.1.0
```

What am I doing wrong? how can I fix this? thank you.

Comment: where is file tree?

Comment: @eisanahardani it's near the top right after I had declared my links and a few lines under.

Comment: It's strange, because the Python docker image is Linux-based, but the error message is about a windows Python environment. Could you remove the `C:/Users/trevo/OneDrive/Desktop/veganet/veganettest:c:/app` volume? The right hand side is wrong anyways, because there's no c: drive in the image.

Comment: @Dauros I figured out the problem, I had to remake my project and the error went away. Thank you though!